# How do I rename multiple files by removing everything but numbers?

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, rename

I want to rename files like:

```
SL Benfica vs. SC Beira-Mar 136.mp4
SL Benfica vs. SC Beira-Mar 137.mp4
SL Benfica vs. SC Beira-Mar 138.mp4
SL Benfica vs. SC Beira-Mar Jogo 074.mp4
SL Benfica vs. SC Beira-Mar Jogo 082.mp4
SL Benfica vs. SC Beira-Mar Jogo 112.mp4
```

But this

```
for f in *.mp4; do echo mv "$f" "${f//[^0-9]/}.mp4"; done
```

Adds a "4" at the end:

```
1364.mp4
1374.mp4
1384.mp4
0744.mp4
0824.mp4
1124.mp4
```

I think that it gets confused with the "4" in "mp4". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `.mp4` suffix before you do the replacement.

```
for f in *.mp4; do
  fname=${f%.mp4}
  mv -- "$f" "${fname//[^0-9]}.mp4"
done
```

I added `--` in case your filenames start with a `-` and removed the `echo`. Be careful.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, the `4` that appears is from the `mp4` extension. The reason is that you are processing the *full* filename in the `${f//[^0-9]/}` statement to remove every occurence of characters that are not digits, which includes the `.mp` part and leaves the `4` from the ending.

You can use `sed` for the purpose:

```bsh
for f in *.mp4; do
  newname="$(sed 's/^[^0-9]*//' <<< "$f")"
  mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

but be sure to test it (as you obviously do, as I can see from your post).

Answer (score 3):

Using `prename` you could run something along the lines of

```
prename 's/^\D*//' *.mp4
```

notes:

- `\D`  a non digit
- `^\D*` sequence of non digits in beginning of the filename
- `s/^\D*//` remove initial non digits, and rename

In some linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu) this command is called `rename`, and in others (e.g. Arch) `perl-rename`.